# Unable to get latest on branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm having an issue.  I have switched to a branch `some-feature`.  I do `git pull origin some-feature` and it says already up to date.  I check a file I know has changed and the changes are not there. I check bit bitbucket and the changes *are* there.

I have tried `git reset --hard HEAD` followed by `git clean --force` and another pull but no luck. Why is git lying to me and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you actually on the right branch?

```
git checkout some-feature
```

Otherwise, check `git log origin/some-feature` and make sure the commit you expected is at the top.

Finally,
Are you sure that `origin` refers to bitbucket? Check the entry for bitbucket in `.git/config`

(*Update*: seems like the local branch `some-feature` wasn't set up to track `origin/some-feature`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch) for now to set up tracking.)

Comment: Yep, on the right branch. Yep, the commit at the top matches the commit reported by bitbucket when I browse that file.  git remote -v reports the correct repo.

Comment: So `origin/some-feature` and `origin` point at different places? The former is correct, and the latter isn't? Maybe try `git checkout origin/some-feature` in order to be explicit.

Comment: That worked. I think the problem is that I created some-feature on another computer. Then on this computer I did git checkout -b some-feature and then tried to pull.  It makes sense that despite the names they are different branches.  I'll remember to checkout that way in the future. thank you.

Comment: Aha. I think you need to set up your local `some-feature` branch to track `origin/some-feature`. I don't know how to do that, but I'm pretty sure it's easy. I the meantime you could try `git checkout some-feature; git rebase origin/some-feature` to attempt to replicate the changes in the 'local' `some-feature` branch.

Comment: .. See this answer for how to set up tracking to link `some-feature` with `origin/some-feature`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch